# Trying to make a leveling system, however it only works once and then stops working?

Tags: python

I'm making a leveling system and it only levels me up once and then stops working. Once it levels me the xp doesn't reset and my level does not go up. Here's the code!

```
level = int(1)
crexp = int(260)
reqxp = int(100)
while crexp >= reqxp:
    level = level+1
    crexp = crexp-reqxp
    reqxp = (reqxp/100)*120
    continue
while 3 > 2:
    pinput = input()
    if pinput == "1":
        crexp = crexp + 60
    elif pinput == "2":
        print(level)
    elif pinput == "3":
        print(crexp)
    elif pinput == "4":
        print(reqxp)
    elif pinput == "5":
        break
```

Comment: Why "3 > 2" and not just "True"? 3 will always be greater than 2. I'm not sure, because it's very unclear what result you *want*, but be aware that the second while loop is not contingent on the first - the first will run, stop, and then your second will start asking for input.

Comment: I tried with True and it still did not work. and the while 3 > 2 part is only for testing. I need the first loop to keep working after the condition has been met.

Comment: The code executes as intended, the level is updated to 3, crexp is 40 and reqxp is 144. Is there any relevant code that you left out of the question?

Comment: I'm guessing you tested it however after the first update it no longer updates when I add xp using "1" and its 250 crexp with 144 reqxp and level 3.

Comment: @Galaxycrasher38 I didn't mean that switching '3 > 2' to 'True' would fix your code, just that they were equivalent and would do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you are not rerunning the 'level up' part of the code. Python generally (when not in a while/for loop e.c.t) reads your code from top to bottom. This means by the time you get into the second while loop the first while loop has finished and will never be run again.
To fix this you want to tell python to recalculate the level and experience variables at certain points - the easiest way to do this is to make the first while loop into a function and call it at the start of the second while loop. You would get something like this -

```
def checkLevelUp(currentXp, requiredXp, currentLevel):
    while currentXp >= requiredXp:
        currentLevel = currentLevel+1
        currentXp = currentXp-requiredXp
        requiredXp = int(requiredXp * 1.2)
    return currentLevel, currentXp, requiredXp


level = 1
crexp = 260
reqxp = 100


while True:
    level, crexp, reqxp = checkLevelUp(crexp, reqxp, level)
    pinput = input()
    if pinput == "1":
        crexp = crexp + 60
    elif pinput == "2":
        print(level)
    elif pinput == "3":
        print(crexp)
    elif pinput == "4":
        print(reqxp)
    elif pinput == "5":
        break
```

Note also the changes to calculating the next required xp - dividing by 100 and then multiplying by 120 is just the same as multiplying by 1.2.

Comment: The xp required by `checkLevelUp()` will reset on each outer while loop, correct? Perhaps this is as the OP intended, but I'm pretty sure what they actually want is to figure out the required xp based on the current level (or, rather, the level they're trying to reach), rather than basing it on an incoming parameter. Currently, if my first call to `checkLevelUp()` is with 100 crexp, I will level to 2 and then return. If the next call is also with 100 crexp, I'll level to three - but I should probably need 120.

Comment: All of which is beside the actual point - which you correctly point out is the structuring of the while loops vis a vis each other.

Comment: @NathanielFord - the xp requirment should change dynamically due to the fact each loop updates the value of reqxp from the return of the function. Copy and paste the code and try it out - you'll see that pressing 1 multiple times followed by 4 will show a higher reqxp value than 100.